# Easyspace host spitting XML error loading site

Tags: xml, http

I have a site hosted with Easyspace and am having some connection troubles. Basically, any attempt to load the site is returning a strange XML error.

I did notice that prior to the site dropping out, any updates I was making weren't displaying, almost as if there was some kind of caching issue. Has anyone else experienced similar problems with Easyspace hosting?

Thanks!
G

Comment: "a strange XML error"? What error?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved - turns out Easyspace were having technical difficulties and their XML parser looked like it had farted. Back up and running :)